# How to apply filters on MongoDBAtlasVectorSearch similarity_search_with_score” of langchain?

Tags: python, mongodb, langchain, vector-search

I am using [MongoDBAtlasVectorSearch](https://python.langchain.com/docs/integrations/vectorstores/mongodb_atlas) and ì want to search for the most similar documents so I use the function [similarity_search_with_score](https://python.langchain.com/docs/integrations/vectorstores/mongodb_atlas#pre-filtering-with-similarity-search).

However, it seems like I am not able to add filters in this similarity_search_with_score function.

This is my code:

```
vector_search = MongoDBAtlasVectorSearch(
        collection=client[os.getenv("MONGODB_DB")]["files"],
        embedding=embeddings,
        index_name=os.getenv("ATLAS_VECTOR_SEARCH_INDEX_NAME"),
    )

results = vector_search.similarity_search_with_score(
        query="What are the engagements of the company",
        k=5,
        pre_filter={
            "compound": {
                "filter": [
                    {"equals": {"path": "uploaded_by", "value": chat_owner}},
                    {"in": {"path": "file_name", "values": file_names}},
                ]
            }
        },
    )
```

This is my index:

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "dynamic": true,
    "fields": {
      "embedding": {
        "dimensions": 1536,
        "similarity": "cosine",
        "type": "knnVector"
      },
      "file_name": {
        "normalizer": "lowercase",
        "type": "token"
      },
      "uploaded_by": {
        "normalizer": "lowercase",
        "type": "token"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However, this gives me the following error :

`pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: "knnBeta.filter.compound.filter[1].in.value" is required, full error: {'ok': 0.0, 'errmsg': '"knnBeta.filter.compound.filter[1].in.value" is required', 'code': 8, 'codeName': 'UnknownError', '$clusterTime': {'clusterTime': Timestamp(1704804627, 1), 'signature': {'hash': b'\xfa\x15s+Q\x1d\xa86]R\xb2!\x9d\xc5b-G\xce\xa6S', 'keyId': 7283272637088792583}}, 'operationTime': Timestamp(1704804627, 1)}`

I also tried like this :

```
        pre_filter={
            "$and": [
                {"uploaded_by": {"$eq": chat_owner}},
                {"file_name": {"$in": file_names}},
            ]
        },
```

But I got this error:

```
pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: "knnBeta.filter" one of [autocomplete, compound, embeddedDocument, equals, exists, geoShape, geoWithin, in, knnBeta, moreLikeThis, near, phrase, queryString, range, regex, search, span, term, text, wildcard] must be present, full error: {'ok': 0.0, 'errmsg': '"knnBeta.filter" one of [autocomplete, compound, embeddedDocument, equals, exists, geoShape, geoWithin, in, knnBeta, moreLikeThis, near, phrase, queryString, range, regex, search, span, term, text, wildcard] must be present', 'code': 8, 'codeName': 'UnknownError', '$clusterTime': {'clusterTime': Timestamp(1704802325, 9), 'signature': {'hash': b'`\xd27-\x81+\x16\xd0a\x14\xc7\x99\xa8\x05|Sx?\x0e:', 'keyId': 7283272637088792583}}, 'operationTime': Timestamp(1704802325, 9)}
WARNING:  StatReload detected changes in 'src/routes/chats/chats.py'. Reloading...
```

How can I use filters in the similarity_search_with_score properly ?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your error message

> '"knnBeta.filter.compound.filter[1](https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/vector-search-pre-filter-using-the-in-clause/259202).in.value" is required'

And based on [this answer in the MongoDB Forums](https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/vector-search-pre-filter-using-the-in-clause/259202) looks like your `in` clause is using `values` instead of `value`. As an example:

```
"in": {
      "path": "fileName",
      "value": model_documents,
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! However I am using values because file_names is an array of strings. So there are multiple values.